# How to make VideoView full screen

Tags: android, android-videoview, landscape, android-fullscreen

I want to play a video in my `Activity` using a `VideoView`,and make it fullscreen and `landscape` mode (with hiding virtual button and status bar)when I click a `Button`.

But it can not hide the virtual button and it has a white line in bottom.
[image: my app]

> This my activity code:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
private VideoView mVideoView;
private String mUrl;
private Button mFullScreen;
private static String TAG = VideoActivity.class.getName();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.video);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    mFullScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"video.mp4");
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(file.getPath());
    mVideoView.start();
    mFullScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enterFullScreen();
            mFullScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy");
}

private void enterFullScreen(){
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//设置全屏
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);//设置横屏
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);//常亮
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
  }
}
```

**video.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="Fullscreen"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this on your landscape mode.

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/video"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
```

Hide virtual buttons add this code:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

**Original size**

```
         DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
         android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) videoView.getLayoutParams();
         params.width =  (int) (300*metrics.density);
         params.height = (int) (250*metrics.density);
         params.leftMargin = 30;
         videoView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**full screen size**

```
         DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
         android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) videoView.getLayoutParams();
         params.width =  metrics.widthPixels;
         params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
         params.leftMargin = 0;
         videoView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Could you try again the xml code i made some changes.

Comment: it can hide the white line but it can not hide that three virtual button @Kristo1990

Comment: and in this way ,it always be full screen but it want it not full screen ,after i click the fullscreen button it change to fullscreen

Comment: check out i added some code that you need to add for the virtual buttons

Comment: yeah the code that you add for the virural button works, and i konw how to do it now ,i can make the VideoView's padding was 0,0,0,0 after i click the button like mVideoView.setPadding(0,0,0,0) All in all thank you very much to help me

Comment: That's good. If this helped you please accept my answer. Happy coding :)

Comment: I find a bug now is when i click other button it will make the padding as usual that has a white line in the bottom i think i should find another way to solve it

Comment: and in this way , it seen like  i cannot exit the full screen but i want to exit full screen

Comment: I am pretty sure that the xml that i gave you works for fullscreen videoview. I cant help you if you are going to do this another way around it.

Comment: if you want to exit the full screen then you need another button.!

Comment: yeah ,I know the xml is work for fullscreen videoview ,but it will make it fullscreen before i click the fullscreen button,so I want setpadding(0,0,0,0) in the button listener,it can work at the first time but when my finger click the  screen it has the white line as usual. Another way ,I want to know how to exit fullscreen .what code should i write?

Comment: this is your xml code it will make it full screen before I click the button ![this is your xml code](http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/large/7bdcf253gw1f0796furrpj20zm1iyk2l.jpg)

Comment: Ok use your xml and try to do this programmatically. I will edit my answer.

Comment: but use it programmatically it will show the white line again

Comment: yeah I try it but it cannot fullscreen ,this is the picture you can have a see [](http://ww2.sinaimg.cn/large/7bdcf253gw1f07asslo8gj21ke0y6wtq.jpg)

Comment: try this 
`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: I had try it at all , you can see it in my code uploaded before T ^ T

Comment: Well dont know how i can help you anymore. i have used this snippets before and they worked for me. maybe you need to change something in your xml in order to remove that white line. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

At Last, I solve it with Kristo1990 and prashantwosti 's help 
My code is :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
private void enterFullScreen(){
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);//设置横屏
        mVideoView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        mVideoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

private void exitFullScreen(){
          this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            mVideoView.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
            isFullScreen = false;
            mFullScreen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            }else {
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,0);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,0);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,0);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0);
            }
            mFullScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mVideoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
```

And at last I override the KEYCODE_BACK to exit fullscreen
I hope it can help you all and thank you again.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for `BackButton`:

```
closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClose);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Log.d("VideoPreview", "onClick Close Button");
            VideoFullscreenActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Take a look: [How to close a VideoView Activity (currently have to press back twice)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679583/how-to-close-a-videoview-activity-currently-have-to-press-back-twice)

Comment: this way is to finish the activity but I don't want to finish the activity , I write the code to exit fullscreen ,code like  getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT);

Answer (score 0):

Here's some snippets from my working app:

in player activity:

```
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

your player_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/video_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".PlayerActivity">

   <VideoView
     android:id="@+id/videoView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,your code help me to find a new way to solve it